# Stripline error on chart

Tags: c#, winforms, mschart

Currently, I can draw stripe lines on the chart but there is some error when I want to draw on the line of the x/ y-axis but  it cannot be drawn.

There is no error for the drawing stripline as there is no message box pop up but still nothing gets drawn.

```
        try
        {


            StripLine stripLine6 = new StripLine();
            stripLine6.StripWidth = 0;
            stripLine6.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
            stripLine6.BorderWidth = 4;
            stripLine6.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDotDot;

            stripLine6.IntervalOffset = Convert.ToDouble(textBox12.Text);
            stripLine6.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Orange;
            stripLine6.Text = "x̅";
            chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.StripLines.Add(stripLine6);
        }

        catch
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error for Stripline 6 to be drawn");
        }
```

[What I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDSsD.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if the combination of

```
StripWidth = 0;
```

and

```
IntervalOffset = 0;
```

results in the whole Stripline not being drawn at all.

Could be a bug, as  per [MSDN:](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.stripline.stripwidth(v=vs.110).aspx)

> **StripLine.StripWidth Property**
>
> A setting of 0.0 will result in a line being drawn; this line will use
>   the BorderColor, BorderDashStyle and BorderWidth property settings for
>   its color, width and style. None of the Back* properties in this class
>   are utilized when the value of StripWidth is 0.0.

To workaround you can set either to a positive value:

```
StripWidth = 0.001;
```

or

```
IntervalOffset= 0.001;
```